# Create mlp custom learner in MLR

Tags: regression, mlr, mlp

Can you help me in creating a "RLearner_regr_mlp.R"?. I need to solve a regression problem with mlp in MLR package but I could not creat its training function and prediction method.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To be able to help you, you need to provide detailed information about your issue. Also there is a dedicated help page for this topic: https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/create_learner.html.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. There is a classif.mlp learner in MLR, I would like to create regr.mlp for regression problems and incorporate it MLR training process. 

I have already followed the link that you shared but I think determining the training function and prediction method is so hard.

Comment: If the answer below helped you, please mark the question as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dedicated help page for this topic in the [mlr-tutorial](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/create_learner.html).

Besides, {mlr} is retired and we won't add any new learners to the package from our side.
If you have troubles yourself, you can make a new learner request at the [mlr3learners repo](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3learners) to be included in the {mlr3} package framework.